# Adding records in Pandas datetime columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data set like below:

```
Value       Time         delta time 
2     2009-05-27 18:45     0:15:00
4     2009-05-27 19:00     0:15:00
1     2009-05-27 19:15     0:15:00
1     2009-05-27 19:30     0:15:00
2     2009-05-27 20:45     1:15:00
```

I have calculated the time different between each rows using the following code:

```
df['deltatime']= df['Date'].diff(periods=1)
```

I need to add records in between records which have a delta time more than 15 min. I want the out put of the code to be something like below with 0 values for the added records:

```
Value     Time             delta time 
2      2009-05-27 18:45    0:15:00
4      2009-05-27 19:00    0:15:00
1      2009-05-27 19:15    0:15:00
1      2009-05-27 19:30    0:15:00
0      2009-05-27 19:45    0:15:00
0      2009-05-27 20:00    0:15:00
0      2009-05-27 20:15    0:15:00
0      2009-05-27 20:30    0:15:00
2      2009-05-27 20:45    0:15:00
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**: [`as.freq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html)

```
new_df = df.set_index('Time').asfreq('15min', fill_value=0).reset_index()
new_df['delta time'] = new_df.Time.diff()

>>> new_df
                 Time  Value delta time
0 2009-05-27 18:45:00      2        NaT
1 2009-05-27 19:00:00      4   00:15:00
2 2009-05-27 19:15:00      1   00:15:00
3 2009-05-27 19:30:00      1   00:15:00
4 2009-05-27 19:45:00      0   00:15:00
5 2009-05-27 20:00:00      0   00:15:00
6 2009-05-27 20:15:00      0   00:15:00
7 2009-05-27 20:30:00      0   00:15:00
8 2009-05-27 20:45:00      2   00:15:00
```

**Method 2**: [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
new_df= (df.resample('15min', on='Time').mean()
         .fillna(0)
         .reset_index()
         .assign(delta_time = lambda x: x.Time.diff()))

>>> new_df
                 Time  Value delta_time
0 2009-05-27 18:45:00    2.0        NaT
1 2009-05-27 19:00:00    4.0   00:15:00
2 2009-05-27 19:15:00    1.0   00:15:00
3 2009-05-27 19:30:00    1.0   00:15:00
4 2009-05-27 19:45:00    0.0   00:15:00
5 2009-05-27 20:00:00    0.0   00:15:00
6 2009-05-27 20:15:00    0.0   00:15:00
7 2009-05-27 20:30:00    0.0   00:15:00
8 2009-05-27 20:45:00    2.0   00:15:00
```

Comment: When I use the first method it sets all values to zero but I need to just set the generated ones to be zero. Do you know why its happening ?

Comment: Can you send me the way you read the data from csv file to write this code? I think ita a matter of reading data. When I use the code (first method) its working with my long code where I generated the datetime column. However, when I want to check ut like in the example I provided here it sets All values to zero. Is it a matter if parse dates ?

Comment: oooh yeah that's entirely possible. Try `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])` before anything. And (not that it should make any difference), but I read in your data using `pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: thanks for you help, pd.to_datetime fixed the problem.